# Do blood pressure and heart rate influence intraocular pressure and to what extent?

Tags: opthalmology

I assume the typical situation for an increase in intraocular pressure is this: on the one hand new vitreous is produced, but on the other hand the exit path for vitreous is blocked for one of many possible reasons.

But inside the visual nerve there is a blood vessel, an artery even. Doesn't that imply that when heart rate and blood pressure increase, eg due to significant physical activity (sports), that also the intraocular pressure would increase?

And if yes, by how much could it increase, assuming that intraocular pressure is at about 15 mmHg at rest? Could it increase beyond eg 21 mmHg?